# How to add Optional Dependencies in Carthage Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, carthage

I create a framework(MainFramework) that uses as optional dependencies other frameworks. User can integrate **MainFramework** only or if needs extra functionality - download optional frameworks.
This works pretty fine when integrating it through Cocoapods like:

```
pod 'MainFramework'
pod 'MainFramework/OptionalFrameworkA'
pod 'MainFramework/OptionalFrameworkB'
```

But I couldn't achieve the same behavior with Carthage. When I add links to optional frameworks into MainFramework's Cartfile, then in the App that uses only 'MainFramework' I get the error when trying to build the app:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OptionalFrameworkA.framework/OptionalFrameworkA

Even optional frameworks removed from the App's runscripts and embended frameworks section.

One important thing here, the optional frameworks should be inside MainFramework, since they use internal functions that can't be available for the users. Also in 'MainFramework' I use conditional import to check if module available:

```
 #if canImport(OptionalFrameworkA)
```

Optional frameworks are too heavy(~50mb) to include them into the app even if don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed] For Carthage I manage to do it only with separate targets for `OptionalFrameworkA` and `OptionalFrameworkB`. Carthage builds each target, so later developers can import only those builds which they needs. If anyone will be curious how it's implemented, I could suggest to check next repos: [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) & [VGSCollect](https://github.com/verygoodsecurity/vgs-collect-ios)